# How do I loop through all the products of a store using Liquid (Shopify)?

Tags: loops, pagination, shopify, liquid

I can't. I know.

Shopify imposes a limit when it comes to the number of products one can loop through on a page.

The current limit is 50.

Actually, **this is not true**.

One can loop through all the products of a store using liquid :

```
{% paginate collections["all-products"].products by 10000 %}

  {% for product in collections["all-products"].products %}

     {% comment %}looping through all 10000 products{% endcomment %}

  {% endfor %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

In the above example, if a store has up to 10000 products I can loop through all 10000 of them. Increasing that *pagination* number will increase the number of products I can loop through accordingly.

What I want to know is whether Shopify will continue to support this (even though they don't like it) and therefore, whether I can build stores using the above without the risk of the `{% paginate collections["all-products"].products by 9999999 %}` becoming deprecated at some point.

Having said that, I would obviously never loop through 10000 products, let alone 9999999 of them. But I definitely want to build stores where I will be looping through more that 500 products in one go for example.

Comment: `pagination` limit is maxed out at 1000. Beyond that it'll either stop at 1000 or give a liquid error. I have had the same issue earlier.

Comment: Great good to know HymnZ! So it means that this "hack" won't work either. You can make this the Answer to the question as this is what I was looking to confirm :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pagination` limit is maxed out at 1000. Beyond that it'll either stop at 1000 or give a liquid error. I have had the same issue earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, I created an "automated" collection with product title is-not-equal-to "really dumb title". I am able to loop over this custom-made allproducts collection.

This store only has 24 products in it, but it seems that this at least gets past the (current) limit of 20 on all_products. Not sure if it would limit to 1000.